# How are the builds pushed from Hudson CI Server to QA/Staging/Production environments?

Tags: build-process, continuous-integration, hudson

Does Hudson support deploying builds based on repository labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the deploy feature in hudson to push successful builds to Production. There are also some post build plugins which can help you with pushes. I use this plugin called the POST build task to call a script which does my push to UAT/Staging (http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task)

For a complete list of plugins, please take a look at this link http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins Look at the Artifact uploaders and Post Build sections.